# ASP.NET MVC3 Import view content programatically on an extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building a state machine which display different action controls (partial views) on the page according to some dynamic value.

I started writing HtmlHelper Extension methods to ouput the proper html for each state. Something like:

```
@if(Model.state == "NEW") {
Html.RenderActionEdit()
Html.RenderActionDelete()
}
```

And to do this I was doing simple methods in the form:

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create("<form><input>..... </form>");
```

But this is rather cumbersome for large bits of html. So, the question is, would it be possible to write this Html on separate views (cshtml files) and then somehow load them and pass the result to MvcHtmlString? Like

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create(View.Load("EditAction.csthml"));
```

I couldn't find a way to load an existing view and then just "include" it on the partial method's output.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. `@Html.RenderPartial("thepartial.cshtml", model);` will pass `model` to the partial view, and render it. There are a couple of other versions too.
2. [`@Html.Action("action", "controller", id)` (see msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx) will pass `id` to the specified action method, and render the view it outputs. This is very convenient if you don't have the model object needed for the partial available in your main view.

In an extension method on HtmlHelper, you could use it like this:

```
public HtmlString YourContent(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return helper.Action("action", "controller", new { id = 1 });
}
```

which in your view would be used by calling `@Html.YourContent()`.

Comment: Hum, I see, but I can't invoke Html.RenderPartial from an extension method as it is an instance method. I know that I can call them directly from the view, but I would like to try it from an extension method!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I'm marking this as answered. My problem was that I was writing these helper methods outside HtmlHelper (ie, regular methods not extension ones). I realized that this only works as an extension of HtmlHelper, as you pointed out.